# How to apply pipe in attribute in Angular html template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

How can I apply angular date `pipe` in my `i` tag? The below code is not working:

```
<i class="fas fa-mouse-pointer font-14 status-icon-active mr-3"
    *ngIf="recentDate"
   [tooltip]="[recentDate| date: 'medium']"> -- error Here
</i>
```

Comment: The value should not be enclosed in brackets: `[tooltip]="recentDate | date: 'medium'"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use angular data bindings or interpolation techniques

```
tooltip="{{recentDate | date: 'medium'}}" // Using interpolation
```

or

```
[tooltip]="recentDate | date: 'medium'" // Data binding
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably accusing interpolation. You should write typescript like

```
<i [tooltip]="recentDate | date: 'medium'">
```

or

```
<i tooltip="{{recentDate | date: 'medium'">
```

Any of these will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace:

```
[tooltip]="[recentDate| date: 'medium']"
```

by:

```
[tooltip]="recentDate | date: 'medium'"
```